# ios autolayout does not change button frame position

Tags: ios, position, autolayout

I have one view, and I set this view on autolayout. When I change the button frame/position in 4s iphone, I am not able to change it. How to change the button position in ios 4s 
note without changing the autolayout property ?

Here is my code :

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    if (screenBounds.size.height == 568)
    {
        // NSLog(@"Our App is running in iPhone5");
    }
    else
    {
        //NSLog(@"Our App is running in iPhone 3GS, 4, 4S");
        [btn_next setFrame:CGRectMake(12,100,120,45) ];
        [getTime setFrame:CGRectMake(151,361,89,162) ];
        [picker_AMPM setFrame:CGRectMake(245,304,55,162)];
        [img_blowline setFrame: CGRectMake(0,418,320,6)];         
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by :

Set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES`, then calls to `setFrame:` at runtime are automatically translated into new constraints.

`translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` will also cause new constraints to be added based on the view's autoresizingMask.

More details are in the section "Adopting Auto Layout" in  [Cocoa Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is because you need to change the constraints of the button, not it's frame. To do this you need to make an outlet for your constraint and change it in code and changing the `constant` property of the constraint. The code would be something like this:

```
self.myConstraintX.constant=newX;
self.myConstraintY.constant=newY;
[self.view layoutSubviews];
[self.containerView layoutSubviews];
```

One important thing to note is to make sure this code is not repeated.